# Graphical binary tree in Android

Tags: android, graph, tree

I'm relatively new to Android and stuck with this problem. 
I need to create a UI with a graphical binary tree. Tree nodes contain some text and a small image. I went through the Android developer guide, but couldn't find a way to do this.

Is it possible to draw a binary tree in Android? If it is, what controls should I use? If possible please tell me where I can find more information as well.

Comment: did you able to find any solution. I am stuck in such kind of problem

Comment: https://github.com/naman14/AlgorithmVisualizer-Android

Comment: Check out this link if it serves your purpose:

http://blog.icodejava.com/tag/binary-tree/

Answer (score 4):

I think implementing the `onDraw` is your best bet here since you need a lot of customization and there is no default component for it.
Please refer to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing) on how to do it.

[Here is a library](https://github.com/naman14/AlgorithmVisualizer-Android) which implements binary tree so you can check out how they are drawing it.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should subclass the View class and implement onDraw(Canvas) method
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html

Comment: @GihanRajakaruna I want to see the promised results :-D

Answer (score 0):

Use "de.blox.treeview:treeview:0.1.0" library. You can find how to do it on [Geeks For Geeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/treeview-in-android-with-example/).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33288368)